# #include <new> not found, but only when the file is referenced from a specific header?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, new-operator, objective-c++

I reference the FBXSDK from a number of files, but one in particular causes this error to crop up.  The particular header just imports the fbxsdk like so:

```
#import "fbxsdk.h"
```

I also reference it from the .mm file, and compiling with just the .mm referencing it works fine.  It's only when I import in the header that the fbxsdk brings up errors like this:

```
include/fbxfilesdk/fbxfilesdk_memory.h:67:15: error: new: No such file or directory
```

and a bunch of `expected '*' before '*'` errors.  I'm guessing it has to do with the compile order, or it's compiling the fbxsdk with a different rule set after reading the initial header?  I'm still learning how to work with different compilers and libraries, so any suggestions or clues as to where to look for a solution would be helpful.

Working with Xcode, in a mix of Obj-C++ and C.

Comment: Is it possible that you are not linking against a proper framework?

Comment: I don't think so, because I use the fbxsdk in a number of other files, and they work as expected.  It's just this one that brings the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you are trying to import `fbxsdk.h` from a `.m` file, not a `.mm` file.  If you're importing `fbxsdk.h` in one of your own `.h` files, you need to be sure that your own `.h` file is only imported by `.mm` files, not `.m` files.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that importing a `.h' by a `.m` would affect it.  How exactly does that work, in terms of compiling?

Comment: The `<new>` header is a C++-only header.  If a .h file contains C++ code, then you can only import it from files compiled as C++ and Objective-C++.  It is unfortunate that people use the `.h` extension for header files that require C++.  This is why the Boost project (for example) uses the `.hh` extension.